# How to get rid of "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Just started my ReactJS and stuck at my very first try.  I have a very basic code that throws "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <".

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>My first ReactJs</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="react.js"></script>
    <script src="script.jsx"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.jsx

```
var MessageButton = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return  (
            <button>Hello World</button>
        );
    }
});

React.render(<MessageButton/>, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Assuming that it could be missing JSX transformer library, I searched for it but couldn't find download anywhere.  I work offline most of the time, so I do not wish to use plunkr or jsbin.  Could do with some help.

Comment: do you have a compiler?

Comment: what line is popping your error ? I don't think you need to use .jsx extension

Comment: `<button>Hello World</button>` is he line popping the error. I tried changing it to other valid html but none helped.

Comment: have you change the extension with .js instead of jsx ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: Specify the type attribute of your JSX scripts so the browser doesn't try to execute them as JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/jsx" src="script.jsx"></script>
```

Second:

Either:

Load the JSXTransformer script (which requires an [older version of React](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/06/12/deprecating-jstransform-and-react-tools.html))

*or*

Compile the JSX using Babel:

Example taken from [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html):

```
babel --presets react src --watch --out-dir build
```